# VB.Net MySQL Connector. Bulk insert stopped working

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been using the code below to populate tables in a MySQL database for a few years and it's been working fine.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public sub Thing(dt as datatable)

            Try
                'dt is datatable object populated from MSsqlServer
                Dim MySQLcmdSelect As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * From " & tableName) With {
                    .Connection = MySQLcnn
                }
                Dim MySQLad As New MySqlDataAdapter(MySQLcmdSelect)
                Dim MySQLcmdBuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(MySQLad)
                Dim MySQLcmd As MySqlCommand = MySQLcmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand()
                MySQLcmd.Connection = MySQLcnn
                MySQLad.InsertCommand = MySQLcmd
                MySQLad.Update(dt)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
                Console.WriteLine("Error when populating " + tableName + ": " + ex.Message + vbCrLf + ex.InnerException.ToString)
                WriteLog(ex.Message)
            End Try
End Sub
```

The problem is, it's stopped working!

The connector seems to be working ok as I can drop tables and create them, but this will not let me bulk insert the contents of the datatable 'dt' into the MySQL table.

It doesn't throw an exception, it just passes over the .update(dt) line as if it were a Debug.Print() line when there's 1000s of rows in dt.

Effectively I'm selectively extracting data from tables in MS SQLserver and bulk uploading them to tables with the same name in MySQL.

a) is this the best way to do it, and
b) why has this suddenly stopped working?

According to phpMyAdmin its Server version: 5.6.51 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

EDIT: Further info... all the SQL commands to drop existing tables and create tables work. It is only the .update(dt) that doesn't work.

Comment: Is the value of `MySQLcmd` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Hi Andrew. The ```MySQLcmd .CommandText``` is exactly what I expect. The odd thing is that the .update(dt) doesn't throw an exception, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are there more rows to update than there used to be? Is the number of rows suspiciously close to a power of 2, such as 32767 or 65535? Have any columns been added to either database? Can you explicitly specify the column names instead of using "*"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's not "updating" Through necessity we delete the MySQL table, recreate it and then insert all the records from dt using the .update(dt) method. This has worked for a few years now and has suddenly stopped.

Comment: which version of the connector and honestly that is a very old version, try a mysql 5.7 or 8.0 with the new connectors in a vm

Comment: Ever tried to just check it with smaller data chunks? Just to check if bulk INSERT works at a lower scale?

Comment: We need more details on "stopped working".

Comment: @RickJames it used to work - now it doesn't :-) As it says, the ".update()" method does nothing where once it would transfer the data to the MySQL table. Now - nothing...

Comment: Does `update(dt)` run a MySQL `UPDATE ...` statement?  Let's see that SQL.

Comment: What is the return value of `MySQLad.Update(dt)`

Comment: @ChrisStrickland if I change it to  ```Dim x = MySQLad.Update(dt)``` x is 0 (zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still can't get the bulk upload to work, but we have redesigned this so that data is inserted into MySQL at the same time we store it in the MS-SQL database and have removed the need to bulk upload.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems with your code could be that the schemas do not match exactly, auto increment columns, or the connection could have been disposed elsewhere (it should be declared local to the method where it is used). Another problem is that `dt` has had `AcceptChanges` called or `LoadOptions` were set incorrectly.

```
    Private ConnStr As String = "Your connection string"
    Public Sub Thing(dt As DataTable, tableName As String)
        'check the datatable - if it is ok then this check is probably not necessary
        Dim changesDT = dt.GetChanges()
        If changesDT.Rows.Count < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No changes to update")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnStr),
            MySQLad As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From " & tableName, cn)
cn.open() ' added by OP
            Dim MySQLcmdBuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(MySQLad)
            MySQLad.Update(dt)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code throw `NullReferenceException` if no changes were made because if no changes were made, `dt.GetChanges()` returns null. Instead of `If changesDT.Rows.Count < 1 Then` it should be `If changesDT Is Nothing Then` . With this change it works well.

Comment: @user9938 Agreed. If the calling code failed to create an instance of DataTable this could happen but it would be rather silly.

Comment: @user9938 Apparently, you missed the fact that I agreed with you. The OP stated `'dt is datatable object populated from MSsqlServer` You can't populate a DataTable without instantiating it.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Still flies over the .update(dt)

Comment: PS. I added a cn.open ;-)

Comment: @Tym I thought the DataAdapter would open and close the connection.

Comment: @Tym Did you include the If statement on ChangesDT?

Comment: @Mary I've always opened a connection manually. Stopped using data adaptors a long time ago, but need to use it for this .update() method. If there's a better way of copying selected data from a MS SQLserver table to a MySQL one I'm all ears. :-)

Comment: @mary - took the .open out and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have "0000-00-00"?  If so, a setting has changed the default -- new versions of MySQL disallow zero dates.  Read about `sql_modes`.

Comment: There aren't any "date" values in there at all, just numbers and strings

Comment: Also... this is for every single table... regardless of content